# Remove gap between 2 chart areas and set minimum and maximum values of Y-axis

Tags: winforms, charts

I am trying to remove space between 2 chart area and want to set minimum and maximum values at run time to Y-axis but strip lines which i have taken in my chart are getting misplaced i.e. sometimes does not display and sometimes display but on wrong place. [click here for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e18s.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the charting library that you are using?

Comment: Visual studio's charting library(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart)